# Is there a way to highlight text but not based on syntax?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

I was thinking about writing a little file viewing plugin, similar to netrw but my own thing, and I'm not sure how to highlight the files differently if there's no syntactic difference between the files. So I would want to highlight directories blue and regular files white, but without writing a "/" at the end of one, and using a syntax highlight to match against it. If the only text in the buffer is:

```
foo
bar
```

how could I highlight foo blue, because foo is a folder?

Comment: You can use the match or textprop apis, probably

Comment: thanks that is exactly what I was looking for, in addition to the matchadd() function, also looks kinda useful.

Comment: Since I don't really have much knowledge about those APIs, I won't leave a full answer; anyone (including Jake the OP) should feel free to write a nice answer :)